# Updating a specific row value in sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database Table which contains a column called `NAME`

```
NAME

a
b
c
a
d
a
b
```

I want to update all the field which contains `"a"` to a different value

Comment: Looks like a homework question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this query (it changes the value of a with z):

```
UPDATE myTable SET [NAME] = 'z' WHERE [NAME] = 'a'
```

I guess that NAME is a reserved keyword, so, I enclosed it in []

Comment: Yeah, it ia a reserved keyword .Thnx

Answer (score 0):

This is more a SQL question than an Android question but the query should be :

```
update table set NAME="new name" where NAME ="a"
```